# how do i parse a div on website with jsoup

Tags: parsing, jsoup

i want to parse something like this:

```
<div class = "1">
   <div class = "2">
      <div class = "3">
         <div class = "4">
         <div class = "5"> value </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

but when i'm using

```
Document d = Jsoup.connect("https://example").get();
    Elements elements = d.getElementsByClass("5");
    System.out.println(elements);
```

i'm getting nothing ;( i've tried a ton of variants but nothing seems to work. How do i do that?

Comment: The class selector is simply `.5`. If you can't get the value, there are several options, among them:  1. You have to add the user agent string. 2. The data is loaded dynamically with js. 3 You have to pass thru a 'landing page' first and get cookies and some other indentifiers from it.

Comment: Try `System.out.println(d);` to see how Jsoup parsed this HTML.